# Zurb Foundation, Media Queries

Tags: html, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I am new to web development, i am trying using foundations media query. However the following code that I have typed inside a style.css file does not seem to work.

What have I done wrong, should it be included in the style.css file.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) { 
    font-size:11ems;
    background:color:red;
    border-left:1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing I can see is you don't seem to be targeting anything inside your media query block. e.g. `.class{property:value;}`

Also, your background color property should be `background-color:red;` and I think it should be `em` instead of `ems` for `font-size`